# Multi-step Form When Resizing on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to create a mobile responsive web app, I've already managed to fit it properly on mobile devices, but I don't want the "second form" to go above the first one, but to create a multi-step form when viewing on mobile devices.

Here's my code so far:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

(I have two forms like this one)

Comment: So where is CSS? What you mean `go above the first one`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for Multistep Form its easy use for you...
and if you are using bootstrap so multi step form is so easy on bootstrap with fully responsive.
[Custome Multistep](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps)

[Bootstrat Multistep](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multi-step-form-wizard-30467045)